# How do I make my character jump, with a curve, in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>

Game::Game(sf::RenderWindow& game_window)
  : window(game_window)
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  // Load the texture for the defender ship
  if (!defenderTexture.loadFromFile("Data/Images/kenney_animalpackredux/PNG/Round/bear.png")) {
    // Error handling: Unable to load defender texture
    std::cerr << "Failed to load defender texture!" << std::endl;
    // Optionally, you can handle this error further, like returning false from init() method.
  }

  if (!backgroundTexture.loadFromFile("Data/Images/lvl2.png")) {
    // Error handling: Unable to load defender texture
    std::cerr << "Failed to load defender texture!" << std::endl;
    // Optionally, you can handle this error further, like returning false from init() method.
  }

  if (!tileTexture1.loadFromFile("Data/Images/kenney_pixelplatformer/Tiles/tile_0091.png")) {
    // Error handling: Unable to load defender texture
    std::cerr << "Failed to load defender texture!" << std::endl;
    // Optionally, you can handle this error further, like returning false from init() method.
  }

  if (!tileTexture2.loadFromFile("Data/Images/kenney_pixelplatformer/Tiles/tile_0091.png")) {
    // Error handling: Unable to load defender texture
    std::cerr << "Failed to load defender texture!" << std::endl;
    // Optionally, you can handle this error further, like returning false from init() method.
  }

  if (!tileTexture3.loadFromFile("Data/Images/kenney_pixelplatformer/Tiles/tile_0091.png")) {
    // Error handling: Unable to load defender texture
    std::cerr << "Failed to load defender texture!" << std::endl;
    // Optionally, you can handle this error further, like returning false from init() method.
  }

  if (!tileTexture4.loadFromFile("Data/Images/kenney_pixelplatformer/Tiles/tile_0091.png")) {
    // Error handling: Unable to load defender texture
    std::cerr << "Failed to load defender texture!" << std::endl;
    // Optionally, you can handle this error further, like returning false from init() method.
  }

  // Set up the defender sprite
  defenderSprite.setTexture(defenderTexture);
  backgroundSprite.setTexture(backgroundTexture);
  tileSprite1.setTexture(tileTexture1);
  tileSprite2.setTexture(tileTexture2);
  tileSprite3.setTexture(tileTexture3);
  tileSprite4.setTexture(tileTexture4);


  // Set the initial position of the defender ship
  // You can adjust these coordinates according to your game layout
  defenderSprite.setPosition(window.getSize().x / 2.0f, window.getSize().y - 100.0f);
  tileSprite1.setPosition(100, 525);
  tileSprite2.setPosition(600, 425);
  tileSprite3.setPosition(100, 300);
  tileSprite4.setPosition(600, 225);

  defenderSprite.setScale(0.35f, 0.35f);
  backgroundSprite.setScale(0.8f, 0.8f);
  tileSprite1.setScale(18.0f, 3.0f);
  tileSprite2.setScale(18.0f, 3.0f);
  tileSprite3.setScale(18.0f, 3.0f);
  tileSprite4.setScale(18.0f, 3.0f);

}

Game::~Game()
{

}

bool Game::init()
{
  if(!font.loadFromFile("Data/Fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"))
  {
    std::cout << "font did not load \n";
  }

  menu_text.setFont(font);
  menu_text.setString("Main Menu");
  menu_text.setCharacterSize(36);
  menu_text.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
  menu_text.setPosition(450, 100);

  description.setFont(font);
  description.setString("Collect all the coins and avoid enemies to win!");
  description.setCharacterSize(18);
  description.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
  description.setPosition(350, 350);

  play_option.setFont(font);
  play_option.setString("Play");
  play_option.setCharacterSize(24);
  play_option.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
  play_option.setPosition(400, 200);

  quit_option.setFont(font);
  quit_option.setString("Quit");
  quit_option.setCharacterSize(24);
  quit_option.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
  quit_option.setPosition(650, 200);

  return true;
}

void Game::update(float dt)
{
  // Check for ship movement
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) {
    bearVelocity = -bearSpeed; // Move left
  } else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
    bearVelocity = bearSpeed; // Move right
  } else {
    bearVelocity = 0.0f; // Stop movement
  }

  // Calculate new ship position based on velocity
  float newBearX = defenderSprite.getPosition().x + (bearVelocity * dt);

  // Check bounds to prevent ship from going out of screen
  newBearX = std::max(0.0f, newBearX); // Clamp newShipX to be at least 0
  newBearX = std::min(newBearX, window.getSize().x - defenderSprite.getGlobalBounds().width); // Clamp newShipX to be at most window width - ship width

  defenderSprite.setPosition(newBearX, defenderSprite.getPosition().y);



}

void Game::render()
{
  if (in_menu)
  {
    // Render the menu
    window.draw(menu_text);
    window.draw(play_option);
    window.draw(quit_option);
    window.draw(description);
  }
  else
  {
    // Clear the window
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    window.draw(backgroundSprite);

    // Render the defender ship sprite
    window.draw(defenderSprite);

    window.draw(tileSprite1);
    window.draw(tileSprite2);
    window.draw(tileSprite3);
    window.draw(tileSprite4);

  }

}

void Game::mouseClicked(sf::Event event)
{
  //get the click position
  sf::Vector2i click = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);


}

void Game::keyPressed(sf::Event event)
{
  if (in_menu) {
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down) {std::cout << "Down" << std::endl;
      // Navigate up in the menu (e.g., move selection from "Play" to "Quit")
      if (play_selected) {
        play_selected = false;
        play_option.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        quit_option.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
      }
    } else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up) {std::cout << "up" << std::endl;
      // Navigate down in the menu (e.g., move selection from "Quit" to "Play")
      if (!play_selected) {
        play_selected = true;
        quit_option.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        play_option.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
      }
    } else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Enter) {std::cout << "enter" << std::endl;
      // Select the currently highlighted menu option
      if (play_selected) {
        // Start the game
        in_menu = false;
      } else {
        // Quit the game
        window.close();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

So I want to make my character jump. this is my Game.cpp file with all my current functions. Currently, I've got my character and platforms rendered in (this is a platformer game). I want my character to jump and if the character is moving, for the character to continue to move during the jump.

Answer (score 0):

**Kinematic approach**

You could use the linear interpolation ("`lerp`") formula, along with some other function that create a curve (`3t^2 - 2t^3` for example). The problem with this is that being kinematic rather than physics-based, it does not respond well to dynamic circumstances such as collisions with other characters, or walls. So I would not use this approach here.

**Simple Physics-based approach**

```
vec2 characterPosition;
vec2 characterVelocity;

//(1) returns scalar speed as positive, negative or zero depending on walk control.
//(2) returns scalar speed as positive (jumping), negative (Falling), or zero depending on jump control.
characterVelocity.x = getScalarValueFromWalkInput(); //(1)
characterVelocity.y = getScalarValueFromJumpInput(); //(2)

//*apply equations of motion*
characterPosition = characterPosition + characterVelocity;
```

You could additionally use acceleration, in which case you would do something like:

```
vec2 characterPosition
vec2 characterVelocity;
vec2 characterAcceleration;

//(1) returns scalar acceleration as positive, negative or zero depending on walk control.
//(2) returns scalar acceleration as positive (jumping), negative (Falling), or zero depending on jump control.
characterAcceleration.x = getScalarValueFromWalkInput(); //(1)
characterAcceleration.y = getScalarValueFromJumpInput(); //(2)

//*apply equations of motion*
characterVelocity = characterVelocity + characterAcceleration;
characterPosition = characterPosition + characterVelocity;
```

...and then you would also need to careful control / limit maximum acceleration and velocity so that things don't move too quickly. Acceleration can give a more realistic / organic feel depending on your desired input controllers.

You will also have to understand how to do 2D collision detection and resolution in this case, which is a whole separate topic. For this reason, many people use libraries like [Box2D](https://box2d.org/), which handle the equations of motion for you, as well as collision detection and resolution.